# htaccess rule to redirect?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a link like `www.example.com/hello-1/hey-2`, now what I want to do is that I want to redirect to this link from `www.example.com/hello-1/hey`. How to write a htaccess rule for this. I have tried searching on it, tried the same way to reduce index.php but that didn't work.Thank you.

See, basically I want people to be redirected when the type www.example.com/hello-1/hey this was my old link. I want them to be redirected to www.example.com/hello-1/hey-2, where this 2 is important as it's passing a parameter for me.

Comment: Also, could you provide an example of [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's possible to do so;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^hello-1/hey$   hello-1/hey-2 [R=301,L]
```